# How can I tell if a key was ever defined in a deserialized JSON object in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I'm using C#/.NET 4.5 to deserialize a JSON object to a native .NET type. The JSON looks like:

```
{
    id: 841,
    runningTime: 33.8643736,
    title: "Test title"
}
```

...and the class it deserializes to looks like:

```
public class Slide
{
    public double runningTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

...using this code to deserialize it:

```
// given serializer is an instance of JavaScriptSerializer
var slide = serializer.Deserialize<Slide>(json);
```

This works just fine and I can read properties on the object as if I was directly reading the JSON.

But, what if `title` is an optional key in the JSON? I can check if it's null after deserializing, but that's not perfect because `title` could have legitimately been set to null in the JSON itself, and I need to know if the key itself was defined. Using some placeholder value for the `title` like `"UNDEFINED"` is also pretty hacky.

So, if I'm using `JavaScriptDeserializer` to deserialize JSON, how can I tell if a key was defined in the JSON in the first place vs. explicitly set to null?

Comment: If you used json.net, you can deserialize to `dynamic` and check if a property is passed. Or you can deserialize to a dictionary and check for existence of the key and map the dictionary to your `Slide`

Comment: or check the json string itself before deserializing

Comment: Not related to your actual problem, but I second the suggestion to use json.net. Something else you get with it is the ability to follow .NET naming conventions: you can give your properties their .NET-standard name of starting with an uppercase letter, but still automatically map them to lowercase JSON property names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume checking for null is not sufficient since the JSON could contain a null.  So you could do this:

```
public class Slide
{
    public bool HasTitle { get; private set; }

    public double runningTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private string _title;

    public string title
    {
        get { return _title;  }
        set { _title = value; HasTitle = true; }
    }

    public int id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now check "HasTitle" to see if the title property was ever set.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to allow the caller to reset `HasTitle` while still leaving `title` set, nor that it's a good idea to allow the caller to set `_title`, bypassing the `title` property setter. But other than that, yeah, it's the same basic idea I posted at about the same time. :)

Comment: I ultimately went with something similar: using a field that gets set to true when the property is set. I was avoiding JSON.NET to minimize the number of dependencies for this program for boring reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing too much of the rest of your code, you can change the way you define your properties. `Nullable<T>` gives a good model for a helper structure, but only applies to value types. A version that also works for reference types, except without the special compiler and runtime support (not needed here), is easily made:

```
public struct Optional<T>
{
  private readonly bool hasValue;
  private readonly T value;
  public Optional(T value) {
    this.hasValue = true;
    this.value = value;
  }
  public bool HasValue {
    get { return hasValue; }
  }
  public T Value {
    get {
      if (!hasValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
      return value;
    }
  }
  public T GetValueOrDefault() {
    return value;
  }
  public T GetValueOrDefault(T @default) {
    return hasValue ? value : @default;
  }
}
```

Add methods as needed.

When you have this, you can then change your class to mark your properties as optional:

```
public class Slide
{
  private Optional<double> _runningTime;
  private Optional<string> _title;
  private Optional<int> _id;

  public double runningTime
  {
    get { return _runningTime.GetValueOrDefault(); }
    set { _runningTime = new Optional<double>(value); }
  }

  public string title
  {
    get { return _title.GetValueOrDefault(); }
    set { _title = new Optional<string>(value); }
  }

  public int id
  {
    get { return _id.GetValueOrDefault(); }
    set { _id = new Optional<int>(value);
  }
}
```

You can then determine whether a property setter was ever called, and add support for explicitly unsetting properties:

```
  public bool IsIdSet() {
    return _id.HasValue;
  }
  public void ResetId() {
    _id = default(Optional<int>);
  }
```